# How do I load a .yml property in a Gradle build script?

Tags: spring, gradle, groovy, yaml

I have .yml file with the following properties:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: auth module
  profiles:
    active: prod
```

My gradle.build script has these settings for the `jar` task:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'auth-module-dev'  // `dev` should come from `spring.profiles.active`
    version =  '0.1.2'
}
```

I want to build jar files with the naming convention `auth-module-%profile_name%.jar` where `%profile_name%` is the value of `spring.profiles.active`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

assume your yaml file has name `cfg.yaml`

don't forget to add `---` at the beginning of yaml

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: auth module
  profiles:
    active: prod
```

build.gradle:

```
defaultTasks "testMe"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.19'
    }
}

def cfg = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().load( new File("cfg.yaml").newInputStream() )

task testMe( ){
    doLast {
        println "make "
        println "profile =  ${cfg.spring.profiles.active}"
        assert cfg.spring.profiles.active == "prod"
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error, because I have more than one document.  * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'amod'.
> expected a single document in the stream
   in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
      spring:
      ^
  but found another document
   in 'reader', line 8, column 1:
      ---
      ^

Comment: When I use loadAll: No such property: spring for class: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$YamlIterable

Comment: i forgot - just add `---` as the first line in yaml. check the updated answer.

Comment: TNX! I Just added first()      def cfg = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().loadAll(new File("src/main/resources/application.yml").newInputStream()).first()

Comment: For completeness, I would add the trailing `...` to the YAML document so you can denote when one ends. Since you ca have multiple YAML documents in the same file. https://yaml.org/refcard.html and https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395