# How to share variables between .yaml and .gradle files?

Tags: android, git, gradle, intellij-idea, yaml

I am developing Android library with CI(Continuous Integration) support in git server. The configuration use a `.yaml` or `.yml` file. The build system that I use is the default one from Android Studio, which is gradle, so I also use `.gradle` configuration files here. My question is, **how can I share variables between those files?** Because I need to upgrade some variables that actually the same from each file, like `ANDROID_API_LEVEL`, `ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION`, etc. It will be inconvenience if I should edit every file to upgrade version. **Is there any best practice that I can use?**

For example, here is my yaml file looks like

```
language: android
sudo: false
dist: precise

env:
  global:
   - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=27
   - ANDROID_EMULATOR_API_LEVEL=21
   - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
   - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
...
```

And here is my project-level gradle file looks like

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.31'
        ankoVersion = "0.10.2"
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 14
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        androidSupportVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
...
```

Let's say I want to share the value of a variable `ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION` in `yaml` file with `buildToolsVersion` in `gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) for reading and writing properties from YAML files.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48320319/9647266) answer, they talk about the same problem.

**Update answer with example**

The implementation is exactly the same since both, Android Studio and Spring (in this case), use Gradle as the main executive buildtool. The link i shared showed the basic principle on how to access YAML properties in your build.gradle and was intended as a how-to-start.

This will synchronise selected `env.global` properties of your build.gradle file with your YAML file. Trivial properties like `language`, `sudo` and `dist` stay untouched by this action. The main file to maintain in this case would be the build.gradle file since the YAML file will be maintained by Gradle.

I wrote a short snippet on how to attain this:

File: **cfg.yaml**

```yaml
language: android
sudo: false
dist: precise
env:
  global:
  - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=27
  - ANDROID_EMULATOR_API_LEVEL=21
  - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
  - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

File: **build.gradle**

```groovy
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.21'
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = '27.202'
}

task updateYAMLFile() {
    def configurationYAML = "cfg.yaml"

    inputs.files buildscript.sourceFile
    outputs.files configurationYAML

    DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions()
    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK)
    options.setPrettyFlow(true)
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options)

    ext {
        updateGlobalProperties = { cfg, name, version ->
            def index = (int) cfg.env.global.findIndexValues { it ==~ /$name.*/ }[0]
            cfg.env.global.set(index, name + '=' + version)
        }
    }

     doLast {
        def cfg = yaml.load(new File(configurationYAML).newInputStream())
        updateGlobalProperties(cfg, 'ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION', buildToolsVersion)

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(configurationYAML)
        yaml.dump(cfg, writer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @UnlikePluto. However, this is related to Android Studio, while your link is for Spring Framework, so the implementation is different. If you know how it can be implemented to Android Studio projects, you can add the example directly in here. Please avoid link-only answer since it is not a good practice. Refer to here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/322677

Comment: I have tried and modify from the link you gave me. It is not what I want like in the question since it just do assertion only inside the gradle task, while I want to **share** variables between yaml and gradle.