# Use value from application.yml file inside build.gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, yaml

I am wondering if it's possible to have a value inside my application.yml file:

```
app:
  constant:
    foo:
      fooValue: 'test'
```

and to get this value and put it into a variable inside my build.gradle file

What I've tried so far:

[How to load yml propery to gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318114/how-to-load-yml-propery-to-gradle/)

I tried the solution in the above link, however

```
def app = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().loadAll(new File("src/main/resources/application.yml").newInputStream()).first()
```

the above in my build.gradle throws an error `'src\main\resources\application.yml (The system cannot find the path specified)'`

Does anyone know how I can fix the error above or of a better solution?

Comment: Do you need to access the value both at build time and at application runtime?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown build time

Comment: Why is it that you want the data in the application's `application,yml` configuration file?  A better plan is to leave that file out of it as mixing Gradle build configuration in the same file with your Micronaut runtime configuration is going to cause confusion.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yeah you're right there is a better way. I'm just a bit inexperienced so thought maybe this was a good idea, but seems like I can do something better. I'm trying to let my build.gradle file know which environment its running inside (dev,qa etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wants to know, adding $projectDir to the start of the file path fixed the issue.

```
def app = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().loadAll(new File("$projectDir/src/main/resources/application.yml").newInputStream()).first()
```

Comment: does it work if it is just `new File("application.yml")`  ?

Comment: @R.G Nope, it kept saying that it could not find the path specified.